# Python: How to create nested XML from a flat datastructure

Tags: python, xml, serialization

I would like to create nested XML (as a string) from a list of dicts with python:

```
toc = [
  {'entryno': 1, 'level': 1, 'pageno': 17, 'title': 'title a'},
  {'entryno': 2, 'level': 2, 'pageno': 19, 'title': 'title b'},
  {'entryno': 3, 'level': 1, 'pageno': 25, 'title': 'title c'},]
```

**level** means *nesting level* and there might be more than 2 levels in my dict. The toc has a fixed ordering (by entryno). Level can only increase by one from one entry to the next but it could decrease by more than one. 
Here is the nested example XML I want to create:

```
<entry id="1">
  <pageno>17</pageno>
  <title>title a</title>
  <entry id="2">
    <pageno>19</pageno>
    <title>title b</title>
  </entry>
</entry>
<entry id="3">
  <pageno>25</pageno>
  <title>title c</title>
</entry>
```

I tried to solve this with string.Template() and iterating over the toc but i got stuck at creating the nested part of the XML. I suspect the solution will be some recursive stuff.

As a programming beginner I am not just interested in a solution but also in **your train of thought to solve this!.**

Comment: Is this a unique solution? Why is entryno with id=2 nested under id=1 and not id=3? There's nothing in the structure that says where it is nested. Is the ordering important? In which case, it might make the job easier (also, missing /entry tag in your example)

Comment: The ordering of the toc is by entryno. So entryno with id=2 is nested under id=1 as it comes after id 1 and is a "level" deeper...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-ugly solution using the ElementTree API. One implementation is included with Python, as xml.etree.[c]ElementTree. Another is lxml.etree, which provides more functionality, including pretty-printing the output.

```
# import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import lxml.etree as et
import sys

toc = [
  {'entryno': 1, 'level': 1, 'pageno': 17, 'title': 'title a'},
  {'entryno': 2, 'level': 2, 'pageno': 19, 'title': 'title b'},
  {'entryno': 3, 'level': 1, 'pageno': 25, 'title': 'Smith & Wesson'},
  {'entryno': 4, 'level': 2, 'pageno': 27, 'title': '<duct tape>'},
  {'entryno': 5, 'level': 2, 'pageno': 29, 'title': u'\u0404'},
  ]

root = et.Element("root")
tree = et.ElementTree(root)
parent = {0: root}
for entry in toc:
    level = entry['level']
    entryno = entry['entryno']
    # create the element and link it to its parent
    elem = et.SubElement(parent[level - 1], "entry", {'id': str(entryno)})
    # create children to hold the other data items
    for k, v in entry.iteritems():
        if k in ('entryno', 'level'): continue
        child = et.SubElement(elem, k)
        child.text = unicode(v)
    # record current element as a possible parent
    parent[level] = elem
# tree.write(sys.stdout)
tree.write(sys.stdout, pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: Using the ElementTree makes this look much better ;). So this will be the way I will solve this...

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you know how to create XML.

Let's assume that 'level' in your data increases if the data is nested in the previous node, and it only increases by 1. If the level decreases, this means that you are not talking about current node any more, but rather about some node above; level == 1 means 'attach at document level'.

- To handle *increasing* levels, you just need to track the previous node. If the level increases by one, you create a new node and make it a child of previous node.
- To handle *the same* level, you need to remember the parent of the previously created node. You attach the new node to that parent, because it's a peer of the previous node.
- To handle *decreasing* levels, you need to step back from previous node several steps so that you're on the right level. Can you see a pattern?

Really you need to remember the whole chain from document level to the previously created node. If `next_node.level == previous_node.level + 1`, you attach it to the end of chain. Else you step back `previous_node.level - next_node.level + 1` items up the chain and use that node as the parent. We assume that level 0 is document level.

A bit of code to illustrate this:

```
def nest(input):
    ret = {'level': 0} # 'document level'
    path = [ret]
    for item in input:
        node = dict(item) # a copy of item, lest we alter input
        old_level = path[-1]['level'] # last element's
        new_level = node['level']
        delta = new_level - old_level - 1
        if delta < 0:
            path = path[:delta]
        children_list = path[-1].get('_children', None) or []
        children_list.append(node)
        path[-1]['_children'] = children_list
        path.append(node)
    return ret

from pprint import PrettyPrinter
pr = PrettyPrint(indent=2).pprint
pr(nest(toc))
```

and you see

```
{ '_children': [ { '_children': [ { 'entryno': 2,
                                'level': 2,
                                'pageno': 19,
                                'title': 'title b'}],
               'entryno': 1,
               'level': 1,
               'pageno': 17,
               'title': 'title a'},
             { 'entryno': 3, 'level': 1, 'pageno': 25, 'title': 'title c'}],
  'level': 0}
```

Under `_children` we list nested nodes.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. And as it seems I won´t be solving this easily with some simple string manipulations but with an xml libary ;.). So I have to dig into that first...

Comment: Both are ugly. This one transforms the input into some weird structure, leaving you to serialise it somehow. If could have just as easily built a (non-ugly) ElementTree instance which needs just one more call to serialise it, and it will automatically take care of any `&` and `<` characters in your titles.

Comment: @John Machin: you are most welcome to post a non-ugly solution and I make it the accepted answer...

Comment: @John-Machin: I could put creation of real XML DOM into the code, but it would bloat the code 2x-3x and obscure the idea by technical details. So I used the most lightweight approach I could quickly invent :)

Comment: @9000: About time you looked at ElementTree, isn't it?

Comment: @Titusz: non-ugly solution posted

Comment: @9000 Still thanks for explaining the concept of transforming the data into a nested structure very nicely. But indeed ElementTree seems to be the right way to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

```
toc = [
  {'entryno': 1, 'level': 1, 'pageno': 17, 'title': 'title a'},
  {'entryno': 2, 'level': 2, 'pageno': 18, 'title': 'title d'},
  {'entryno': 3, 'level': 3, 'pageno': 19, 'title': 'title e'},
  {'entryno': 4, 'level': 4, 'pageno': 20, 'title': 'title b'},
  {'entryno': 5, 'level': 5, 'pageno': 25, 'title': 'title c'},]

blevel=0
ret=""
for i in toc:
  while blevel >= i['level']:
    ret += "%s</entry>\n" % (" " * blevel)
    blevel-=1
  blevel=i['level']
  ident=" " * i['level']
  ret += "%s<entry id=\"%i\">\n" % (ident, i['entryno'])
  ident+=" "
  for a in i:
    if not a in ['entryno','level']:
      ret += "%s<%s>%s</%s>\n" % (ident,a,i[a],a)
while blevel > 0:
  ret += "%s</entry>\n" % (" " * blevel)
  blevel-=1

print ret
```

Comment: You've written python so ugly it looks like good-looking perl :)

Comment: Missing some duct tape: What if one of the titles is `Using a Smith & Wesson product on a <duct tape> coder`

Comment: you proved me wrong... it is indeed possible to do this with some "simple" string manipulations ;.)